# Prometheus Query in Grafana filtering metrics between specific hours

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have the following query that I am using in Grafana with a Prometheus datasource:

```
(probe_success{instance="$target"} == 0)[30d:1m]
```

This query is returning the time series data for the `probe_success` metric over the last 30 days with a resolution of 1 minute. It works fine.

I want to expand the query. It should only return the data between 09:00 AM - 05:00 PM. I tried it like:

```
(probe_success{instance="$target"} == 0) and (hour() >= 9 and hour() <= 17)[30d:1m]
```

Unfortunately, it seems the query is wrong:

```
parse error: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types
```

I am not seeing what is wrong with the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query:

```
(
  probe_success{instance="$target"} == 0
    and on()
  (hour() >= 9 and hour() <= 17)
)[30d:1m]
```

It uses `on()` modifier in order to match any time series on the left side of the [and](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) operator to any non-empty time series on the right side of the `and` operator.

When the `on()` modifier isn't set, then Prometheus tries to find time series pairs with identical sets of labels on the left and the right side of the `and` operator. There are no such pairs, since the left-hand side returns time series with at least `instance="$target"` label, while the right-hand side returns time series without any labels. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The query is treated as:

```
(probe_success{instance="$target"} == 0)
and
( (hour() >= 9 and hour() <= 17)[30d:1m] )
```

Thus, the `[30d:1m]` attaches only to the right-hand side of the `and`. Try this instead:

```
(probe_success{instance="$target"} == 0 and hour() >= 9 and hour() <= 17)[30d:1m]
```

Comment: Thank you. The query doesn't result any error anymore, but the result is empty.

Comment: `(probe_success{instance="$target"} == 0 and hour() > 5)[30d:1m]` doesn't return data neither. Here is `5` just an example, whatever I make it it doesn't return data. Even without `== 0` I am not getting any data.